# Activate type with generic params array set to null

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

Let's say I have this ctor:

```cs
public MyType<T>(int myInt, string myString, params T[] myObjects) { }
```

I could set the params array itself to `null` (rather than pass a null into the array):

```cs
MyType(1, "foo", (T[])null)
```

Let's say I want to do that dynamically. I tried this:

```cs
var args = new object[] { 1, "foo", null };
var myType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyType), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, args, null);
```

But that throws a `MissingMethodException`.

If I change the ctor's `params T[]` to `params object[]` then it works, but I prefer to keep the generic form.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance` seems kind of a convience wrapper round `Type.GetConstructor`. The latter has the advantage that you can specify the ctor's signature explicitly, which will help you out in this case:

```
//usage:
var intItem = CreateGeneric<int> (1, "int_str", null);
var strItem = CreateGeneric<string> (2, "str_str", null);

public static MyType<T> CreateGeneric<T>(int myInt, string myString, T[] array)
{
    //specify c'tor signature and get ctor-info
    var types = new [] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(T[])};
    var ctor = typeof(MyType<T>).GetConstructor( 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, types, null);
    
    //create instance
    var args = new object[] { myInt, myString, array };
    var instance = (MyType<T>)ctor.Invoke(args);
    
    return instance;
}
```

Full demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h3lpZc